# Digital Ocean App build error with NextJS imports/exports

Tags: next.js, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I have a problem with building app process in Digital Ocean, I have an app already deployed and I have implemented a big refactor in the code structure, in my local I can make a build perfectly but when I tried to make build in digital ocean I have received an error with imports and exports [image]

I have the same node version in Digital Ocean and local (v16.15.0)

any idea about the problem?

Comment: Could you post a list of the files you have in ./src/components/Toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the bug, it was a problem with git, in my refactor I changed some filenames to use camelCase and the ToolBar file was being cached with its previous name.

I mean

- previous name:
  src/components/Toolbar/ToolBar.tsx
- current name:
  src/components/ToolBar/ToolBar.tsx

this failed because in the git repository it kept the old name while in my local repository it had the updated name.